# ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential : How to check in backend server that the credential is valid?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ios13

I m implementing User Authentication with Sign in with Apple. when the authentication succeeds, the authorization controller invokes the authorizationController:didCompleteWithAuthorization: delegate function, which the app uses to store the user’s data in the keychain.

```
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential { 

      .. send the authorizationCode / identityToken / user and email to the server. 
         server must verify that everything is valid and is yes login the user ...

  }
}
```

How in my back end server can I verify the authenticity of the authorization ? Is their any apple endpoint available somewhere (like google does with https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=) to validate for me the authorization ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact your backend for what type of login is supported by backend. If they are using appleIDCredential.authorizationCode or  appleIDCredential.identityToken, use them.

For my case i was using firebase, then this can be done using OAuthProvider which can be created using :

```
OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: <#T##String#>, idToken: <#T##String#>, rawNonce: <#T##String?#>, accessToken: <#T##String?#>)
```

[image]  Source: Apple docs

Comment: you didn't understand the question :( I want to verify the authenticity of the authorization

Comment: For backend you need to implement this : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api

Comment: thanks, but how to do exactly ? I can't find with endpoint to call :(

Comment: GET https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys 

The response would be like :
`
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "kid": "AIDOPK1",
      "use": "sig",
      "alg": "RS256",
      "n": "lxrwmuYSAsTfn-lUu4goZSXBD9ackM9OJuwUVQHmbZo6GW4Fu_auUdN5zI7Y1dEDfgt7m7QXWbHuMD01HLnD4eRtY-RNwCWdjNfEaY_esUPY3OVMrNDI15Ns13xspWS3q-13kdGv9jHI28P87RvMpjz_JCpQ5IM44oSyRnYtVJO-320SB8E2Bw92pmrenbp67KRUzTEVfGU4-obP5RZ09OxvCr1io4KJvEOjDJuuoClF66AT72WymtoMdwzUmhINjR0XSqK6H0MdWsjw7ysyd_JhmqX5CAaT9Pgi0J8lU_pcl215oANqjy7Ob-VMhug9eGyxAWVfu_1u6QJKePlE-w",
      "e": "AQAB"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: You can read this article: https://sarunw.com/posts/sign-in-with-apple-3/

Comment: thanks manav, but I can not do anything with this key, I m under delphi their is no tool to play with jws key. I need a endpoint! you mean their is no endpoint with apple to validate a key ?